# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing using ng-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

My angular project is complete and working fine. Problem I am having is that after implementing ng-route for navigation **my bootstrap navbar will open but will not collapse.** I checked for similar solutions on stack overflow and tried many  and they did not work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
--- HTML code ---

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#/">Big Blue</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#/">Home </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#overview">Overview </a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#map">Map </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

------ app.js code -------
var app = angular.module("bigBlue", ["ngRoute"]); /* New module called big blue */


app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        template: '<div main-slide-show></div>' // I moved my slideshow directive into the context of the index 
    })                                          // instead of the context of the entire application.
    .when('/overview', {                        // pulling the slideshow directive out of the markup
        templateUrl : 'overview.html',
        controller : 'whaleController'
    })
     .when('/map', {
        templateUrl : 'map.html',
        controller : 'MapController',
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally collapsing/showing is usually a style thing.so make sure to inspect that element and see whether the class is applying to that element and if that class has a style applied to it.

In some cases the existing class might be overridden by the other custom styles .so remove all the custom CSS and load only angular CSS.

Comment: this is not a styling issue it has to do with ng-route and the abbreviations  in ahref tags. when I use index.html or maps.html i dont have the issue with closing or collapsing the navbar here is a simular issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227296/when-i-use-ngrouter-navbar-is-not-collapsing

Comment: Well I found what the issue was. I had     <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> loaded on each page. I took this script out of the other html pages and the collapse feature works fine on all other pages. Now the script only runs on my index.html page only.